# Prerender.io for Angularjs apache server

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, prerender

I've been trying make http://prerender.io work for my website.
I'm pretty sure I've been following their instructions correctly, but when I run the website through with the Googlebot simulator, then it shows that it's not reading the site correctly.

I've been following the guidelines here:
https://prerender.io/getting-started 
My website is called www.justbuythisgame.com

I have this in my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "MyTokenIsCorrectAswell"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
    RewriteEngine On

    <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_

        # Only proxy the request to Prerender if it's a request for HTML
        RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent))(.*) http://service.prerender.io/http://justbuythisgame.com/$2 [P,L]
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I have also added this to my header, even tho it should have no effect on how google crawls the index.html

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

This is what it shows me when I crawl the site, where you can see that it's not getting any of HTML

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 22 Apr 2014 09:49:43 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Tue, 22 Apr 2014 09:37:23 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: Tue, 22 Apr 2014 09:49:43 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Content-Length: 1983
Keep-Alive: timeout=3, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="title" content="Just Buy This Game" />
  <meta name="description" content="JustBuyThisGame is a website that collect data about the most played games, from different websites. We use this data to create a simple list where you easily can see which trending game is the most popular and best rated.  If you buy any of the games we suggest, you won't regret it!">
  <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
  <meta name="language" content="en" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta name="fragment" content="!">
  <base href="/">
  <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
  <!-- build:css styles/vendor.css -->
  <!-- bower:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/select2/select2.css" />
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <!-- build:css({.tmp,app}) styles/main.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js'></script>
  <!-- endbuild -->
</head>
<body ng-app="justbuythisgame" ng-cloak>

    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
      <![endif]-->

      <div ng-include src="'views/layout/header.html'"></div>
      <div ng-view></div>
      <div ng-include src="'views/layout/footer.html'"></div>

      <!-- Add your site or application content here -->

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/select2/select2.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-select2/src/select2.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.reveal.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>

    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/filters.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.4/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.5.0/angularfire.min.js"></script> 
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Can you make sure you have mod_rewrite.c and mod_proxy_http.c turned on?

Comment: I have just talked with my host, and they say they dont support mod_proxy, does that mean I cannot use prerender?

Comment: @Prerender.io Is this the only solution?

Comment: mod_proxy_http is necessary for proxying the request to Prerender.io. A redirect will not work, so a proxy is necessary. Sorry for the inconvenience!